# "In what ways does Strindberg show...?" vs. "In what ways do Strindberg show...?"

Tags: grammaticality, subject-verb-agreement, grammatical-number

Personally, I think the former is correct. My question is *why* this is the case. How would I know which pronoun is the one with which the verb agrees?

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. I think you might show all of your thinking on the matter, then ask about anything that you are not sure of.

Comment: Who or what is 'Strindberg'? There is a possibility that notional agreement may be available if 'Strindberg' is a metonym for a company etc.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/August_Strindberg I just had to look it up.

Comment: Similar: [“What questions {is/are} your data team hoping to answer?”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/80218)

Comment: The subject of "does show" is the singular noun "Strindberg," so "does" is correct.  (The only plural noun in sight is "ways," which is not the subject of "does show" but the object of the preposition "in".)

Answer (score 2):

The subject is Strindberg, which is singular. Therefore, the verb 'does' agrees with it; 'do' doesn't. He/she/it does. They do.

There are no pronouns in the sentence.